# Tree Traversal Function in Java or SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have an following Scenario where I need some help.

1. user_profile table (user_id, name, address, city)
2. parent_user table (parent_id, user_id)

If I pass a parent_id as input, it should get me all child/sub-child user's profile information till particular depth(for ex. till 5th level).

For ex(parent_id -> user_id): 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 2 -> 6

So considering this values, when I pass 1 as input, it should retrieve user profiles of user ids 2,3,4 ,5 and 6.

Can I achieve this using an SQL query itself?

Or using code?

This is what I have tried so far. But I don't see it as an efficient one and an properly working one.

```
//Still not clear with idea of level or depth
void getAllChild(int parent_id, int depth) {
 int count = 0, user_id = 0;
 List listChild = runSQL("SELECT user_id FROM parent_user WHERE parent_id = "+parent_id);
 List<Map> subList;
 for (int i = 0; i < listChild.size(); i++) {
  user_id = listChild.get(i));
  Map userProfile = runSQL("SELECT * FROM user_profile WHERE user_id = "+user_id);
  subList.add(userProfile);
  getAllChild(user_id, 2);
 }
}
```

Please help me with this

Comment: This is not possible with a single SQL statement in MySQL because it still does not support recursive queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is rather bad in querying recursive data. Your approach is basically OK. One obvious problem with you code is that you store the result of each recursive call in a local subList, which is not returned to the caller. The other problem is, that you don't check the depth

There are several ways to fix this: either make subList a parameter of the method, and pass it on to each recursive call.

```
void getAllChild(List<Map> subList, int parent_id, int depth) {

 // check whether maximum depth is reached
 if (depth < 0) {
   return;
 }
 depth--;

 int count = 0, user_id = 0;
 List listChild = runSQL("SELECT user_id FROM parent_user WHERE parent_id = "+parent_id);
 for (int i = 0; i < listChild.size(); i++) {
  user_id = listChild.get(i));
  Map userProfile = runSQL("SELECT * FROM user_profile WHERE user_id = "+user_id);
  subList.add(userProfile);
  getAllChild(subList, user_id, depth);
 }
}
```

or return the subList as a result, and add it to the subList of the calling method:

```
List<Map> getAllChild(int parent_id, int depth) {

 // check whether maximum depth is reached
 if (depth == 0) {
   return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
 }
 depth--;

 int count = 0, user_id = 0;
 List listChild = runSQL("SELECT user_id FROM parent_user WHERE parent_id = "+parent_id);
 List<Map> subList;
 for (int i = 0; i < listChild.size(); i++) {
  user_id = listChild.get(i));
  Map userProfile = runSQL("SELECT * FROM user_profile WHERE user_id = "+user_id);
  subList.add(userProfile);
  subList.addAll(getAllChild(user_id, depth));
 }
 return subList;
}
```

Comment: Let me try this and see if list is giving me all datas.

Comment: But how can I implement depth. Lets say If I want to stop getting datas till 4th level, how can it be done in this function?

Comment: one solution: pass the number of remaining levels as parameter, decrease it by one at the beginning of the method, and don't call the next level if 0 has been reached.

Comment: you mean inside the for loop, i need to decrement depth and pass depth as parameter?

Comment: I changed my example code. See the check at the start of the method, and the changed recursive call.

Comment: Actually *SQL* is quite good at doing recursive queries, MySQL is not though

Comment: OK, I fixed the example code. But you *are* allowed to think for your own, and debug the code :-)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how would you do it in SQL?

Comment: @ThomasStets I fixed it myself. That is why I deleted that comment. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the tips. Will try to change to Postgres if possible.